# Why does select case cut my for loop in half?

Tags: go

In the following code snippet, `tasks` is a buffered channel of length 30 that is populated with exactly 30 elements. I'm writing a `for` loop to operate on each task, which is read in from a channel.

```
for i := 0; i < len(tasks); i++ {
    fmt.Println(i)
    select {
      case task := <-tasks: 
        fmt.Println(task)
        // Do something

    }
}

fmt.Println("Done")
```

However, this for loop only runs from 0 to 14. When I vary the length of this channel (which depends on the number of task elements I have), the for loop always only runs for half of `len(tasks)`. Why is this the case?

Background: 
I use a buffered channel for the tasks because I intend to execute each task in a goroutine, and tasks are dealt with if they fail. But I've currently cut code down to a select case in a for loop, and I'm confused about why the select case causes the for loop to only execute for half the time. I confirm that this for loop has finished executing, and that after the last execution, `i` is equal to 14 (channel length is 30).

Comment: Please don't put tags in the titles. You have the tags for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`len(task)` decreased if you read from `tasks`

Use empty `for` to iteratively read all from task.

```
for {
    select {
    case task := <-tasks:
        fmt.Println(task)
        // Do something
    }
    if len(tasks) == 0 {break}
}
```

Or alternatively you can use range:

```
for task := range tasks {

    fmt.Println(task)
    // Do something

    if len(tasks) == 0 {break}
}
```

Do not forget to `break` this cycles if you don't want to lock you goroutine.

Comment: I don't know what the code is exactly for but generally, that's not the best way to process items in a channel. `while` may still has race condition depending on how items are added to the channel. I suggest using range loop and close the channel when you're finished with it.

Answer (score 6):

`len(tasks)` is re-evaluated at each iteration. So the value is 30, then 29, then 28, ... Finally, `len(tasks)` crosses `i` at the middle, that's why it only prints half the values.

So, what you can do is storing the length in a variable:

```
n := len(tasks)
for i := 0; i < n; i++ { ... }
```

Or, you can simply write

```
for len(tasks) > 0 { ... }
```

If you want to consume all the elements, the `range` operator works:

```
for task := range tasks { ... }
```

Also, remember to close the channel after you're done using it.

Comment: So in the spirit of curiosity, I tried all three of these strategies. The first two work fine. The last one `for task := range tasks { ... }` has an interesting side-effect. Basically in the `//do something` portion, I call a goroutine that operates on the task. When we use `for task := range tasks { ... }`, the task that the goroutine operates on is always the first one it receives from the channel, unless you pass the task variable as a parameter to the goroutine. Why is it that `task :=` defined in `for select` does not have this requirement (i.e. you can directly use the local var)?

Comment: Thank you for the answer btw.

Comment: @lingz, that's the thing with loops in Go. The loop variable is allocated ones and gets overwritten on every iteration. The closure receives a pointer to it, not a copy. Because of that your goroutines will operate on the same value from the last iteration. There're two solutions - https://play.golang.org/p/utTHzgcx4C https://play.golang.org/p/pJnzf_zPYX

Answer (score 0):

Because you take element from channel, its length decreasing..
Take a look on this sample, I think it will be clear for you:
https://play.golang.org/p/TC3HymIlhs